# html Button Hitbox moved on Safari (Mobile and Mac)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML button. It is fully functional on Google Chrome (Web browser) but if I test my website on Safari (macOS) and Safari (iOS) the Hitbox of the button is misplaced at around 50px over the button. Is there any way to fix the button only if the Clients using Safari mobil or Safari Mac?

[image: If the cursor is on the Button. It's deactivated]
[image: If the cursor is slightly over the Button. It's activated]

If the cursor is on the Button. It's deactivated

If the cursor is slightly over the Button. It's activated

[image]

```css
.swiper-container .text-container{
 padding-top: 17%;
 width: 40%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.dark-colors .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, .dark-colors .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, .dark-colors .submit:hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .submit:hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .submit:hover{
 background: #798E9D;
 border-color: #798E9D;
 color: white; 
}
.dark-colors .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, .dark-colors .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, .dark-colors .submit:hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .submit:hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .submit:hover {
background: #798E9D;
border-color: #798E9D;
color: white;
}
.swiper-container .btn {
 margin-top: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.dark-colors .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white), body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white), body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white), .dark-colors .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white), body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white), body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white), .dark-colors .submit, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .submit, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .submit {
border-color: #fff;
color: #fff;
}
.swiper-container .btn {
margin-top: 40px;
display: inline-block;
}
.swiper-container .btn {
margin-top: 40px;
}
.btn, .button:not(.selectric-button), .submit {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 2px solid #151515;
background: transparent;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1;
font-weight: 600;
color: #151515;
line-height: 34px;
padding: 0 35px;
}
.dark-colors .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .btn:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, .dark-colors .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .button:not(.grey):not(.alt):not(.white):hover, .dark-colors .submit:hover, body.dark-theme:not(.logo-dark) .submit:hover, body.light-theme.logo-light:not(.menu-open) .submit:hover{
 background: #798E9D;
 border-color: #798E9D;
 color: white; 
}
.swiper-container .text-container{
 padding-top: 17%;
 width: 40%;
 display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
.swiper-container .text-container{
 padding-top: 6%;
 width: 70%;
 display: inline-block;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
.swiper-container .text-container{
 padding-top: 13%;
 width: 70%;
 display: inline-block;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
 h1{
 font-size: 20px;
 text-transform: none;
 }
.swiper-container .text-container{
 padding-top: 38%;
 width: 88%;
 display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
       <h1>"This is the headline."</h1>
       <p>This is the autor </p>
     <a href="https://google.com" class="btn">Button Deactivated</a>
</div>
```

```
    .swiper-container .btn {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.btn, .button:not(.selectric-button), .submit {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid #151515;
    background: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #151515;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
```

Comment: posting the style used would be great in order to help, meanwhile try adding display:inline-block;

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

try to use specific prefix browser :

```
Chrome: -webkit-
Firefox: -moz-
Internet Explorer: -ms-
iOS: -webkit-
Opera: -o-
Safari: -webkit-
```

in your case , you need to use `-webkik-` before `css` element like this :

```
.btn, .button:not(.selectric-button), .submit{
    -webkik-text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

and do that with unstable element only

Comment: The Problem is. I don't know which part is unstable. I tried to debug every line of code added by me, but I couldn't find the issue.

Comment: I will try this code , and i give you my  feedback as soon as , but you should use prefix css anyway